# Противопоставление с союзом "но"

Tags: орфография, частица-не, наречия

**На улице не холодно, но и не жарко.**
Как правильно написать: слитно или раздельно? Вроде есть союз "но", а в интернете везде раздельно. Почему?

Answer (score 2):

**На улице (хотя) не холодно, но и не жарко.**

Это уступительная конструкция (хотя....но) с отрицанием противоположных признаков.

Сравнить: **На улице не холодно и не жарко, а нормально.** Противоположные признаки отрицаются, при этом подразумевается средний вариант.

У Розенталя с союзом НО рассматриваются другие (сопоставительные) конструкции вида "комната небольшая, но уютная".

Comment: Думается, тут важно не то, что уступительная конструкция (вот пример уступительной конструкции со слитным написанием: комната хотя небольшая, но уютная), а то, что выражено отрицание указанных признаков.

Comment: Автор вопроса спрашивает про союз НО. Розенталь  сравнивает предложения с противопоставлением (союз А, НЕ пишется раздельно) и сопоставлением (союз НО, НЕ обычно пишется слитно). Поэтому можно ошибочно считать союз НО признаком  слитного написания НЕ.

Comment: Думаю, следовало бы дать более четкую формулировку, показать, почему НО не всегда признак слитного написания. Думаю, дело в том, что здесь не "два вполне совместимых утверждения" (Розенталь), а два отрицания. Это ключ к пониманию ситуации.

Comment: По-моему, вы усложняете ситуацию. Не улице не холодно и не жарко (отрицание двух противоположных признаков, объяснение раздельного написания НЕ). На улице (хотя) не холодно, но и не жарко.  Переход к уступительной конструкции, раздельное написание НЕ сохраняется.

Answer (score 0):

Если частица **не** имеет значение отрицания, то с наречиями она пишется раздельно.

С союзом **а** такая конструкция двойного отрицания — не противопоставления! — невозможна (*на улице не холодно, а не жарко*), а вот с союзом **но** и усилительной частицей **и** — вполне.
Признаки и понятия в этом случае не противопоставляются друг другу, а отрицаются, и результат (смысл) получается усредненным, промежуточным:

**На улице не холодно, но и не жарко** (тепло).
Он учился не хорошо, но и не плохо (удовлетворительно).
Обычно передвигались не быстро, но и не медленно (со средней скоростью).

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:
*Денек так себе ― серо, дождя не было в Москве, но ближе к югу брызгал иногда. **Не холодно, но и не жарко*** (Н. Н. Козаков. Дневник);
*И вполне справедливо, что неуклюжий увалень Остросаблин, летавший **не плохо, но и не особенно хорошо**, стал его ведомым* (Н. К. Чуковский. Балтийское небо);
*Он сел за мой письменный столик между двух окон, придвинул к себе бумагу, обмакнул перо в чернильницу и стал писать ― **не быстро, но и не медленно***... (В. П. Катаев. Алмазный мой венец);
*«Газик» ехал **не быстро, но и не очень медленно*** (Ю. В. Трифонов. Последняя охота).

[**НЕ с наречиями**](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.57)

Comment: Ссылка на lampa.io не открывается. ["Примеры провалившихся стартапов: Lampa.io](https://trends.rbc.ru/trends/education/5d89fde49a794757c2c21830).

Comment: Я дополнила свой ответ примерами из Нацкорпуса и поправила ссылку.